# How to mimic URL navigation in javascript web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, architecture

I am writing a pure javascript web app that will rebuild its main view dynamically as users navigate through it, appearing as if it is a different page each time.  Ideally, I'd like to have that appear to the end user as if they are navigating to different URLs, and also allow direct access to a particular view, via that custom url.

I'm wondering:

- Is there a best practice for doing this in a Javascript app?   Should
  I be pushing and popping the window.location stack (to maintain
  history?)
- Should I use query arguments ala ?arg1=val1&arg2=val2 to
  prevent having to modify the window location?
- Is this kind of 'Mega App' (whole app loaded in JS a single time) architecture a bad idea for some reason?

I suspect this is an easy answer for an experienced dev.

I have my own working solutions of a couple of different ilks for various apps I've developed, but am looking to standardize on the most common/appropriate standard way of doing this.

FWIW I'm using (mostly) pure Javascript because 3rd party libraries come, go, evolve and change quickly, and I've developed a basic framework that I know well which I'd like to stay solid over time, with minimal external dependencies.

Comment: you describe a SPA. single page app. query arguments are part of the location, and changing them reloads the page. you should use `history.pushState` if you can support the urls on the backend.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  Is there a way to mimic navigation to different URLs from within a single page app codebase? I've heard of apache/php url rewriting rules to do similar, but am wondering if I can keep this logic within the app.

Comment: yeah, `history.pushState`

Comment: Thanks again Dan.  I think you're hinting at the part I'm still wondering about when you say "If you can support the urls on the backend."  I know how to manipulate what's showing on the front end in the browser, and its history, but not how best to support the SPA architecture on the back end.   In other words is there a best practice way to field a bunch of incoming URLS and direct them all to load the same SPA with different query args, which would then presumably push the history state to make them appear as the original requested URL.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: you can serve the same page on all those urls, then use client js at boot to look at what url was actually requested and handle it all from there. common techniques include htaccess url rewrites/redirects, using server error handlers to serve content on un-mapped pages, and actually putting shells\aliases\copies on all the url endpoints. if you can't get all the backendpoints serving something that at least re-directs to the SPA (if not serves it), then you should use hash/hashbang navigation.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I really appreciate your guidance.